# Powerline works in Vim but not bash

Tags: macos, bash, vim

I upgraded to Mavericks last night, and the only thing that broke was powerline in bash. So I tried reinstalling it according to the instructions, but have been getting some errors.

It still works in vim, ipython, as expected.

However, bash gives me the error:

```
bash: powerline: command not found
```

I'm setting it up as instructed in [the documentation](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#installation) by putting the following line into my .bash_profile:

```
. /Users/USERNAME/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: No. But you can use powerline's issue tracker, donnt you think?

Comment: [Done! I will update if I find anything out.](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/issues/685)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved thanks to Rafacas on the powerline issue tracker.

[https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/issues/685#issuecomment-28494806](http://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/issues/685#issuecomment-28494806)

By adding the following to my .bash_profile, powerline is fixed.

```
if [ -d "$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin" ]; then
    PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"
fi
```